# Pandas, sorting days whilst preserving order

Tags: python, pandas

I've received a CSV file that is a combination of several other csv files.

It has a datetime index (in the format of '2017-01-16' , year, month, day)
However, two problems arise.

1. The combination was not done in order.

   ```
           Date        string        number (different)
   1     2017-01-16   stringvalue     90
   2     2017-01-16   stringvalue    912  
   3     2017-01-16   stringvalue     29 
   4     2017-01-17   stringvalue    883
   5     2017-01-17   stringvalue    223
   6     2017-01-17   stringvalue    211
                  (...)
   230   2015-04-30   stringvalue      908
   231   2015-04-29   stringvalue       28
   232   2015-04-29   stringvalue        9
   233   2015-04-30   stringvalue       98
   234   2015-04-30   stringvalue      909
                   (...)
   450   2017-03-30   stringvalue  348
   ```
2. No time has been provided (the actual day is the smallest number, yet each days holds around 10 values, that need to be kept in order)

I resolved the first problem by peforming

```
    df = df.reset_index()
    df = df.sort_values('Date')
    df = df.set_index('Date')
```

This correctly orders the index, but messes up the ordering within each day. Is there a way to sort the dates, but keep the original order within the days intact?

Comment: can you show more data ? maybe 20 rows ?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), the default sort is not stable.  Try `df = df.sort_values('Date', kind='mergesort')`

Comment: Thanks for your repsonses, I will edit the original question to show more rows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

first convert the `Date` column to `datetime` type if needed

```
df = df.reset_index().sort_values(by=['Date', 'index']).drop(['index'], axis=1)
```

This will reset the index, creating a temporary column called `index`. Then sort using both the `Date` & `index` columns, and finally drop the `index` column. leaving the data frame sorted by `Date` and the order in which they appeared in the original CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

By using a new para and prefix the original order :

```
df['G']=df.groupby(level='Date').cumcount()
df
Out[125]: 
                 string  number  G
Date                              
2017-01-16  stringvalue      90  0
2017-01-16  stringvalue     912  1
2017-01-16  stringvalue      29  2
2017-01-17  stringvalue     883  0
2017-01-17  stringvalue     223  1
2017-01-17  stringvalue     211  2
2015-04-30  stringvalue     908  0
2017-03-30  stringvalue     348  0

df.sort_values('G').sort_index().drop('G',1)
Out[124]: 
                 string  number
Date                           
2015-04-30  stringvalue     908
2017-01-16  stringvalue      90
2017-01-16  stringvalue     912
2017-01-16  stringvalue      29
2017-01-17  stringvalue     883
2017-01-17  stringvalue     223
2017-01-17  stringvalue     211
2017-03-30  stringvalue     348
```